# Enable to set button font in button action in swift5

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to change text of button button action. The font of the button not taken custom font. It will take default font. Please help on this issue I am enable to resolve this issue.
Heare is my code

```
@objc func moreAction(_ sender :UIButton) {
    
    if fromBtn == "more"
    {
       fromBtn = "less"
        sender.backgroundColor = .clear
        sender.setTitle("- Less", for: .normal)
        sender.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Lato-Bold",size:14)
        index = sender.tag
        tblView.reloadData()
    }
    else{
        fromBtn = "more"
        sender.backgroundColor = .clear
        sender.setTitle("+ More", for: .normal)
        sender.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Lato-Bold",size:14)
        index = sender.tag
        tblView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Both fonts are equal?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added the font to xcode [(here's the guide)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app) and it matches the name?

It is also possible to reduce the number of repeated lines :)

```
   fromBtn = fromBtn == "more" ? "more" : "less"
    sender.backgroundColor = .clear
    sender.setTitle(fromBtn == "more" ? "more" : "- Less", for: .normal)
    sender.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Lato-Bold",size:14)
    index = sender.tag
    tblView.reloadData()
```

Comment: In button action it con't change font with system font also.